# Clarification on Root Test

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Suppose I have $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \ln(1 + \frac{1}{n})$. If I apply the root test, I get this:

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\ln(1 + \frac{1}{n})} = 0 \lt 1$

I know the series diverges; what have I done wrong?

Comment: How did you get that limit? It's wrong since $\ln(1+1/n)\approx 1/n$.

Comment: The limit is $1$, not $0$.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\log\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)=\log(N+1) $$ is a telescopic sum, you do not need the (inconclusive) ratio test to prove divergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $0\leq x\leq 1$, the cancave property of $\ln(1+x)$ implies 
$$\ln(2)x\leq \ln(1+x)\leq  x.$$
Hence
$$1=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\left(\frac{\ln(2)}{n}\right)^{1/n}\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\sqrt[n]{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/n}=1$$
which means that, in this case,  the root test is inconclusive.

However, in order to show that the series is divergent one of the two inequalities is quite useful:
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)\geq {\ln(2)}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I think $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\sqrt[n]{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}=1$.